# How to programmatically clear application data in unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I`ve been developing android game in unity3d. My app uses a lot of storage memory so I wanna clean it up after close (user presses the quit button and all cached memory gonna reset). It should work like the "Force Stop" on device. I wrote the method:

```
private void deleteData() {
    String packageName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    runtime.exec(""+packageName);
```

I have following errors in unity editor:

The name `getApplicationContext' does not exist in the current context.

The type or namespace name `Runtime' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

I should import "Runtime" but I couldn`t find how to exactly do it in c# script. Is it possible to implement Android sdk methods in c# scripts? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to make you proper module to do that, you can just delete cache using `Caching.ClearCache();` inside Unity, it will delete all the cache created by the application. Also if you want to delete just the player preferences you can use `PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll();`